# PHP: utf8_encode doesn't work, empty json_encode?

Tags: php, mysql, json, encode, collation

I have the following code:

```
$rows=array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo $row["titel"];                           
    $rows[] = array_map('utf8_encode', $row);
}
echo json_encode($rows);
```

Somehow the output is empty, although I take use of the "json_encode" function. The collation of my columns distinguishes between utf8_bin and utf8_general_ci.
"echo $row["titel"]" outputs the title of every entry my table contains, so I guess the error has to occur in the encode.

I would appreciate every answer :)

Comment: what does `print_r($rows);` show?

Comment: it shows something like "Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 178 [signatur] => SO0027 [barcode] => 467 [komponist] => Caray, David [titel] => Suite for Xylophone and Orchestra [titelzusatz]..........". This goes on for the whole table.

Comment: ok, than what does `function_exists('json_encode');` return: true or false?

Comment: it returns "1", so true I guess

Answer (score 4):

your can use this idea :

```
$rowUtf8encode[]=array_map('utf8_encode',$row);
$rows[]=array_map('json_encode',$rowUtf8encode);
echo($rows);
```

it work funny

Comment: The result is different. OP wants **one** JSON encoded string and not an array of **several** JSON strings

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you'ree missing php package : "php-xml".
Make sure that you have "php-xml" ( or "php5-xml" ) package on your server.

you can check by running folloing command on your server :

```
rpm -qa | grep 'php-xml'
```

or

```
rpm -qa | grep 'php5-xml'
```

Comment: @Force0234 create .php file with only string `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and check json section, especially json support

Comment: It says I'm using PHP Version 5.5.15, and Json 1.2.1 with Json support enabled

Answer (score 0):

Let the datebase do the encoding!

First you should know a few things:

- MySQL's latin1 is **not** ISO 8859-1 but CP1252! See the difference [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Latin_character_sets_%28computing%29#Comparison_table).
- `utf8_encode` encodes only from ISO 8859-1 to UTF-8
- To convert encodings you should better use [mb_convert_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) (or [iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php))
- `mysql_` functions are deprecated! Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead! (look for prepared statements)
- `json_encode` generates error messages you can get by calling [json_last_error_msg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php)

So let's say your Application works with `latin1` encoded strings. Then you should just change the character set for the mysql connection when needed:

```
//Change to utf8
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$result = mysql_query($sqlQuery);
$rows = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($rows);
//Back to latin1 (if needed)
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'latin1'");
```

Comment: The code didn't change anything...the echo still doesn't output anything. 
I've inserted the mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); above my query.

Comment: Did you print out the results of `json_last_error_msg`? Did you enable display_errors? -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php/6575502#6575502

Comment: yeah, I have entered the error_reporting(-1); and ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); at the beginning of the file. It only says that I should use mysqli in the future.

Comment: And what about `json_last_error_msg` **after** `json_encode`?

Comment: Oh sorry, it says "Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded"

Comment: use [mysql_set_charset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php) **Note:**
This is the preferred way to change the charset. Using mysql_query() to set it (such as SET NAMES utf8) is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have done your connection change the charset.
This is due your Database Charset Configuration.

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "UsrChingon", "PwdChingon", "DbChingona");
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");